# Error al intentar clonar un select

Tags: javascript, django

Estoy realizando unas practicas con formset, y los estoy generando con javascript para hacerlos de forma dinamica, pero estoy teniendo unos problemas y es que al momento de clonar el select, este no se muestra en el template pero si en el codigo html:

Este es el codigo que genera el navegador en el html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esto es lo que se genera en mi plantilla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi template:

```
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset %}
    <div id="tareas">
        <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
            <i class="material-icons prefix">bookmarks</i>
            {{ form.type_task }}
            <label for="end_date_id">{{ form.type_task.label }}</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
            <i class="material-icons prefix">bookmarks</i>
            {{ form.name }}
            <label for="end_date_id">{{ form.name.label }}</label>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
<button type="button" class="btn red" onclick="agregar();">agregar tarea</button>
```

Y este es el script:

```
const agregar = () => {
  const formset = document.querySelector('#id_task_set-TOTAL_FORMS');

  const selectt = document.querySelector('#id_task_set-0-type_task').cloneNode(true);
  selectt.name = `form-${formset.value}-type_task`
  selectt.id = `id_form-${formset.value}-type_task`
  const inputt = document.querySelector('#id_task_set-0-name').cloneNode(true);
  inputt.name = `task_set-${formset.value}-name`
  inputt.id = `id_task_set-${formset.value}-name`

  document.querySelector('#tareas').appendChild(selectt)
  document.querySelector('#tareas').appendChild(inputt)

  formset.value = parseInt(formset.value) + 1;
}
```

**Editado**

hice unas verificaciones y el select no se mostraba por la falta del estilo, soy un completo novato en javascript asi que esta es mi solucion, se que no es la mejor pero funciona, agradeceria un consejo sobre como escribirlo mejor.
Este es mi html:

```
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset %}
    <div id="tareas">
        <div class="input-field col s12 m6" id="type_tasks">
            <i class="material-icons prefix">bookmarks</i>
            {{ form.type_task }}
            <label for="end_date_id">{{ form.type_task.label }}</label>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
<button type="button" class="btn red" onclick="agregar();">agregar tarea</button>
```

Y asi quedo el script:

```
const agregar = () => {
  const type_task = document.querySelector('#type_tasks').cloneNode(true)
  type_task.childNodes[2].nextElementSibling.children[3].name

  document.querySelector('#tareas').appendChild(type_task)
}
```

Comment: Dentro del ciclo estás generando múltiples div con `id="tareas"`. Los ID deben ser únicos, de lo contrario, los nuevos elementos se agregan siempre en el primero. Aparte, estás clonando solo _select_ e _input_, ¿qué pasa con sus contenedores?

Comment: estoy revisando pero el id tareas no se repite, y para clonar solo estoy haciendolo con el select y el input, asi no tenga estilos con eso no seria suficiente para que almenos se muestre?

Comment: Tienes `{% for form in formset %}` que, hasta donde sé, es para crear un ciclo. Si se trata de solo un elemento, supongo que no tiene mucho sentido el _for_. En cuanto a que no se muestran luego de clonar, puede depender de los estilos CSS.

Comment: que extraño pues el id no se duplica, he probado varias cosas pero no encuentro el error hay alguna forma de clonar los estilos que tienen los select e input?

Comment: Deberías revisar los estilos de #tarea y los contenedores de cada elemento clonado, seguramente ahí encontrarás alguna pista. Puede editar la pregunta para agregar el CSS relacionado para ver si podemos ayudar.

Comment: id tareas no tiene estilos y los estilos que tiene el select y el input son los de materialize

Comment: Revisa la [documentación](https://materializecss.com/select.html) se requieren los contenedores e inicialización; además, se trata de nuevos elementos, por lo que la inicialización tal vez deba delegarse.

Comment: ya lo edite podrias verificar por favor